# Error message not shown for Nullable type in FLuentValidation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, fluentvalidation

I have problem with Fluent Validation.

I want to check the validation so the property must be filled greater than another property.
here is the code :

```
public decimal? MonthlySalesNet { get; set; }
public decimal? MonthlySalesGross { get; set; }
```

and  here is the validation :

```
RuleFor(x => x.MonthlySalesGross.Value).GreaterThan(x => x.MonthlySalesNet.Value)
            .When(x => x.MonthlySalesGross != null && x.MonthlySalesNet != null)
            .WithMessage("blahblah");
```

the validation was working but the message was not shown. am I missing something?

when I was changed decimal to not nullable type and reconfigure the validation, the error message validation was shown. it`s weird for me,,Thanks

Comment: I have crossposting in fluent validation forum at codeplex.
here is the answer : http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/discussions/266845

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I posted the same answer over on the [FV forum](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/discussions/266845))

The message doesn't display because it thinks it's associated with the wrong property. When you use RuleFor(x => x.MonthlySalesGross.Value), it associates the rule with a property called "Value" rather than with the MonthlySalesGross property.

FluentValidation v3 adds better support for nullables (I blogged about this [here](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2011/04/29/fluentvalidation-v3-better-handling-of-nullable-types/)), but at present this only works with constant values, not expressions that reference other properties. I'm planning to expand the nullable support to work with cross-property validators with v3.1, but for now you can work around this by manually overriding the property name. This will re-associate the error with the correct property:

```
RuleFor(x => x.MonthlySalesGross.Value)
    .GreaterThan(x => x.MonthlySalesNet.Value)
    .When(x => x.MonthlySalesGross.HasValue)
    .OverridePropertyName("MonthlySalesGross");
```

(note that you also have to include a null check with a When clause).